# How to create zigzag shape using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-shapes, pseudo-element

Sometimes I see this type of shape and corner on web design. [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYWlg.jpg)
I have highlighted in red, please help how to create it using css.

[image: image reference]

Comment: There is a `clip-path:` in CSS which can be used to create multiple type of shapes.

Comment: @mehedyh you will need to post code what you have tried before asking question otherwise it will be removed. Please add whatever code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using CSS [pseudo selectors](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) and [css-shapes](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/).

Here is the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/eirenaios/pen/voWezV).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #e6e2bc;
}

nav.navigation {
  background: #23272a;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

nav.navigation ul {
  background: #23272a;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav.navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -1rem;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
}

nav.navigation ul li:after,
nav.navigation ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

nav.navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #a14f29;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bb6c45;
  background: rgb(163, 84, 45);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, rgb(163, 84, 45) 0%, rgb(141, 66, 35) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, rgb(163, 84, 45) 0%, rgb(141, 66, 35) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgb(163, 84, 45) 0%, rgb(141, 66, 35) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#a3542d", endColorstr="#8d4223", GradientType=0);
}

nav.navigation ul li:hover>a i {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

nav.navigation ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgba(35, 39, 42, 0.9);
  background: rgb(163, 84, 45);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, rgb(163, 84, 45) 0%, rgb(141, 66, 35) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, rgb(163, 84, 45) 0%, rgb(141, 66, 35) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgb(163, 84, 45) 0%, rgb(141, 66, 35) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#a3542d", endColorstr="#8d4223", GradientType=0);
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transform: translate(-50%, -35%);
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}

nav.navigation ul li a i:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(35, 39, 42, 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

nav.navigation ul li a p {
  padding: 2.8rem 2rem 0.625rem;
  background: #e6e2bc;
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
}

nav.navigation ul li a p span {
  background: #e6e2bc;
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

nav.navigation ul li a p:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 23px;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #e6e2bc;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav.navigation ul li a p:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 33px;
  right: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #8d4223;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav.navigation ul li:last-child a p:before,
nav.navigation ul li:last-child a p:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
        <p>Work <span>Work hard, dream big</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        <p>Deliver <span>Deliver fast and responsively</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
        <p>Work <span>Work hard, dream big</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        <p>Deliver <span>Deliver fast and responsively</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```